# How to insert string into each continuous tab using regexp?

Tags: regex, sed

I want to insert a string into **each continuous tab**.

The format of input data is like this:

```
Column1\tColumn2\t\t\t\tColumn6....
```

This is my code

```
sed -e 's/\t\t/\tString\t/g'
```

There are 4 continuous tab, so I expect 3 'String' was inserted.

```
'Column1\tColumn2\tString\tString\tString\tColumn6......
```

But I got the result, only 2 'String' was inserted.
There are inserted between each pair.

```
'Column1\tColumn2\tString\t\tString\tColumn6......
```

How do I get the correct result ?

Comment: `Sed` makes this task more difficult because it lacks of look-ahead and look-behind assertions. Are you stuck with it? If so look at the loop commands (`b` and `t`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Birei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773159/birei) pointed out, this is difficult to do with `sed` regular expressions because it cannot use look-ahead and look-behind assertions.

On the other hand this is easy in `perl`:

```
$ echo -e "Column1\tColumn2\t\t\t\tColumn6...." | perl -pe 's/\t(?=\t)/\tString/g'
Column1 Column2 String  String  String  Column6....
```

That is, replace *TAB that is followed by a TAB* with *TAB + "String"*.

Answer (score 3):

You can make this command recursive:

```
$ echo -e "Column1\tColumn2\t\t\t\tColumn6...." | sed ':a;s/\t\t/\tString\t/g;ta'
Column1 Column2 String  String  String  Column6....
```